# How to get weather report for a particular date using weatherbit.io api even timezone changes?

Tags: python, json, datetime, timezone, weather-api

I am using weatherbit api to get historical weather report. It responds based on UTC or GMT time. But my timezone is different.

**For example**

```
api_values_call = requests.get('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/history/hourly?key=yourapikey&city=seattle,WA&start_date=2018-08-12:00&end_date=2018-08-12:24&units=I')
api_values = api_values_call.json()
```

It returns weather report  **GMT/UTC 2018-08-12:00  to   2018-08-12:23**
with timestamp.

If i convert the **utctimestamp to datetime** with timezone('America/Los_Angeles') It starts previous day time (i.e) Los_Angels time is **GMT-7:00** Hours.

So I am getting report from **2018-08-11:17** since GMT-7 is applied to given timestamp. But i need weather report for full day.

How can i get weather report from 2018-08-12:00  to   2018-08-12:23 even the timezone changes.

Comment: Just request the time according to the time you need transformed in UTC time. So if you look for 2018-08-01-12:00 in your local time (GMT-7:00) ask for 2018-08-01-19:00.

Comment: Hi Gozy4.. My requirement is to get full day report. If i am giving start_date=2018-08-11:19&end_date=2018-08-12:24 means it shows error "Only 1 day per request i…s, or upgrade your key." I had  200 free requests for historical data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved through set date intervals **start_date=2018-08-12:07&end_date=2018-08-13:07** to get **2018-08-12 date full day weather report**.

The history call can hit 24 hours so we can set time based on your timezone.

Then you just convert the timestamp GMT/UTC to your timezone.

**Day Light time changes** also important because sometimes it will increased or decreased.

So find the UTC offset time and use dynamically.

**For Example:**

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
dt = datetime.strptime(given_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
offset = int(tz.utcoffset(dt).total_seconds() / 3600.0)
```

The given time 2018-08-12:**07** is utcoffset time. Now I can get full day report correctly.